# Can local storage sessionID be included in all Nextjs requests?

Tags: next.js, local-storage, middleware

I'm creating a website and using a 3rd party service that allows users to authenticate themselves. Once they are authenticated, this service stores a sessionID in the user's local storage. In addition, I have a _middleware.ts file that I would like to use to protect certain routes (i.e., only certain users should be able to access '/protected').

Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically include this sessionID (that is in the user's local storage) for every page request that their browser sends to the server (or if this is possible, on only the requests that are for protected.tsx)? That way, if a user gets routed to '/protected', the _middleware.ts file will take a look at the request, verify that the sessionID is valid and whitelisted to access the page, and the respond with the protected.tsx page (or redirect them if they don't have the right permissions).

If anyone knows how to do this (or knows specific downsides to this approach), would love the help!

Comment: A lot of places say that using localStorage to store sensitive data is bad. I've never really understood this but who am I to argue. There are libraries that can obscurity the data in localstorage for this. In regards to attaching them to requests, you can use Axios interceptors to accomplish this. Or use a dedicated auth library. Nuxt auth works great for my nuxt apps. Whatever is equivalent to Next I don't know.

Comment: Using axios interceptors would be ideal, but I don't know what NextJS uses for their page requests (i.e., I don't know if they use axios in their backend)

Comment: @Issayah, the reason of why storing sensitive data on local storage is considered bad is that if some hacker get control of your pc or if the app is vulnerable to xss attack, he can steal that sessionId from your browser and access the protected routes pretending to be you. So libraries to obscure data don't prevent the access to the data at all, it's just one more obstacle for the hacker to bypass.

Comment: @DimitriBorgers, complementing my previous comment, a good way to avoid this security issue is to store the sessionId in a cookie with the flag http-only, this kind of cookie is sent within a response from the server and it's not accessible with javascript, so it's not vulnerable to xss attacks, also you can send this cookie on every request if you are using a library like axios setting withCredentials to true, or with fetch using credentials: 'include'

Comment: @DimitriBorgers, but as you are using a middleware for authentication, i think you can move all the protected pages to a folder named protected inside the next pages and move the middleware to this folder, that way the middleware only runs against the pages that you want to protect, some good references about what i'm talking: [execution order of middlewares](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware#execution-order), [http-only cookies](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly), [xss attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)